# Grabbing users email and sending invite requests to his friends, How does it work?

Tags: php, invite, yahoo-messenger

I have a since in which when users register, I need to ask them to invite their contacts from YahooMessenger. But sadly, I have no clue as to how to even begin. Any answers or links would be awesome.

Comment: They have a word for it, and it's called "Spam"

Comment: No, I don't mean it like that. I meant the legit one's. Just like Facebook has, when you create a page or a group!

Comment: Professor Xavier. Thank you so much. I wish i could kiss your bold head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to consult yahoo api doc depeding on the contact fields you need.

this would help

http://developer.yahoo.com/social/rest_api_guide/contacts_table.html

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this from one of our fellow Stackover flow member.  [How do I invite people from MSN, Yahoo into my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915311/how-do-i-invite-people-from-msn-yahoo-into-my-application?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Or may be this will be little helpful too. http://phplegend.wordpress.com/2008/09/20/importing-yahoo-contacts-using-curl-and-php/

Comment: Thanks. I prefer your first line, as I am not working with wordpress.